# diff-so-fancy to compare files not under git version control

Tags: diff

I really like the character-level highlighting of [`diff-so-fancy`](https://github.com/so-fancy/diff-so-fancy).

How can I use it to compare files without using `git`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this issue](https://github.com/so-fancy/diff-so-fancy/issues/220#issuecomment-282040462) it seems `diff-so-fancy` currently requires `git`-formatted input to achieve correctly coloured output.

As a work-around:

```
dsf() { git diff --no-index --color "$@" | diff-so-fancy }
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1181976/365890) for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

If what you want is to compare files that are not under git, you can simply use `git diff --color file1 file2 | diff-so-fancy`.

If both files are in the same git repository, you'll need to use `git diff --no-index --color file1 file2 | diff-so-fancy`.

Comment: Is there one command that will work in any circumstance?

Comment: The second one will work in any case.